# android button id declaration

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have set the button id in xml file but while I tried to find the id of the button it showing an error
xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnrotation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rorationbtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbox"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

java file

```
public class rotation extends AppCompatActivity {
    AppCompatButton rotate;
    ImageView imgbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rotation);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Rotation");
        imgbox=findViewById(R.id.imgbox);
        rotate=findViewById(R.id.btnrotation);

    }
```

error
does not contain a declaration with id 'btnrotation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rebuild your project and run again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a bug in android studio, you can try close and reopen Android Studio. If it doesn't work, you can invalidate caches or clean project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on Invalidate Caches from top Toolbar (File) ,  and then click on Invalidate & Restart. Thank You